# How to read each of the values in a nested dictionary using Python 3 and create a similar dictionary after modifiying a value

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, recursion

I am trying to do something like this. I would like to read each of the keys and values in the following dictionary and do some operations, say, find each of the values that is lower than `90` for `Grade2` and increase it to `90`. Finally, create another dictionary with these modifications.

**Input:**

```
markssheet = {
  "Schools": {
    "ABCElementarySchool": {
      "Grade1": {
        "Ethan": 92,
        "Joyee": 89
      },
      "Grade2": {
        "Rifat": 92,
        "Jason": 88,
      },
      "Grade3": {
        "Sophia": 95,
        "Hassan": 93,
      }
    },
    "EdisonElementarySchool": {
      "Grade1": {
        "Ethan": 91,
        "Joyee": 90
      },
      "Grade2": {
        "Ethan": 79,
        "John": 92
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
updated_markssheet = {
  "Schools": {
    "ABCElementarySchool": {
      "Grade1": {
        "Ethan": 92,
        "Joyee": 90
      },
      "Grade2": {
        "Rifat": 92,
        "Jason": 90,
      },
      "Grade3": {
        "Sophia": 95,
        "Hassan": 93,
      }
    },
    "EdisonElementarySchool": {
      "Grade1": {
        "Ethan": 91,
        "Joyee": 90
      },
      "Grade2": {
        "Ethan": 90,
        "John": 92
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can accomplish this with 4 different `for` loop with `key, value` and 4 `if` conditions, but that is not something I can use with any dictionary. Some values can be at the further levels of nesting. In that case my code will not work.

So, I am wondering if I could use a shorter loop with something like recursive function so that it works on any dictionary, but I do not know how. If any other method works for any dictionary, that is also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a recursive function, like this one:

```
def transformMap(sheet):
    for k in sheet:
        if isinstance(sheet[k], int) and sheet[k] < 90:
            sheet[k] = 90
        if isinstance(sheet[k], dict):
            transformMap(sheet[k])
```

Note that it changes the fields values in place without creating another dictionary.